# How to Create file name with Slash in it for Path traversal attack?

Tags: owasp, directory-traversal, lfi

Yes I've read forums that says Forward Slash (/) is invalid character in a file name since it being File Separator in Windows and *nix based machines. But Without creating such an exploit file, I think attacks like ZipSlip won't be possible, Isn't it?

Most Zip Slip attacks involve creating an File with a slash character and when languages like Java use File IO with ZipEntry name, writes to some directory other than intended. So how is this possible?

Ref : https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the first line of the third paragraph of the page you reference:

> The vulnerability is exploited using a **specially crafted archive**...

You don't *create a file* with a slash in it (and then put that file into an archive), but you create an *archive* that *says* it has a file with a slash in it (so when it is extracted it "confuses" the extractor/operating system and creates a file where it shouldn't).

Depending on the nature of an archive, and its internal format, creating an archive could conceivably be as easy as binary-editing an existing archive (e.g. changing `SafeNamedFile.sh` to `../../../evil.sh`), but is more likely to need altering the source code of the archive-creation utility to embed what would normally be an illegal filename.

Comment: I get it. My question is more about such _craft_ing technique to create such a file payload. Can you guide towards some utilities i can start looking at and if needed to modify source to create one?

Comment: Sorry, no. If you want to craft such an attack, you'll have to do the work.yourself.

Comment: @Subramanian there are easily findable scripts/MSF modules from the same authors, I believe.

Comment: I do think this answer properly answers the question as currently phrased.